# Is there an inspiration gallery on the internet that includes the settings/techniques the photographer used to take the photo?

Tags: metadata, camera-settings

I am in the very beginning stages of photography and still having trouble with the basics, namely choosing the best settings for different situations. I've found the best way for me to learn is to see photos (typically posted here) along with the settings the photographer used to take the original photo.

I've started looking at galleries like Flickr to get inspiration/see what others are doing, but I still can't break down what they did to get the photo (ie, "what settings were used to capture this photo of a flying bird?"). Is there a gallery or some specific place where people post photos with details on the settings/technique/process they used to get the photo? Or will I just have figure this out over time?

Comment: have you tried to google something like "great pictures and how they were made". Also, you can post image you like here and ask: how was it made? Community will suggest possible technique

Comment: @JamieHammond Flickr give users the option of displaying or not displaying EXIF info with photos posted. Many Flicker users do leave the EXIF info visible. Many others do not. Sometimes the way an image is processed may strip some or all of the EXIF info. In general, images that are produced using multiple images that are stacked or combined usually do not display info such as TV, Av, and ISO since it may vary for each exposure that went into making the shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not get you there 100%, but this may help some. I focus on headshots and "strobist" lighting and there is a Flickr group titled "strobist.com". That group specifically posts photos that are based on "strobist" (off-camera lighting) techniques. When you open a pic, you can view the exif settings and read the comments from the photographer explaining his/her setup for the pic. In fact, one of the guidelines in posting pics to this group is that the photog must post comments on how the pic was taken. I've pasted excerpts from those guidelines below. This has helped me with my interest in off-camera lighting and portraiture. I am able to scan the group gallery, click on a photo, and see the relevant data and comments. Since you are already a Flickr member, you can check out this group to see details & comments for each pic.

Separately, "strobist.com" is very popular site itself ... it has a whole curriculum that takes you from beginner to advanced on off-camera lighting.

[Excerpt from strobist.com Flick Group rules:

"1. We are specifically about off-camera flash, so photos posted to the group pool should reflect that. Sadly, people miss this rule all of the time, opening the door for these kinds of threads. Don't be that guy. ... (FWIW, on-camera flash is fine if it is used to trigger other off-camera flashes.)

2. Images posted to the pool must include the following lighting details, in the caption of the photo (or in the first comment): the number of flashes used, where the flashes are placed in relation to the subject or camera, how the flashes were modified (umbrella, soft box, beauty dish, snoot, etc.) and how they were triggered. If you do not want to have the lighting info in your caption, please place it in the first comment. We want to make it easy for people to find."****]

Comment: The mention of EXIF tags is the most generally applicable part of this answer, but it's slightly hidden. It might be worth expanding a bit on that.

Comment: there is also strobox.com where you can find info about lighting setups and camera settings